# Set Filter on selected column in .csv file

Tags: excel, powershell

using the following line in my script to output data into a .csv file:

```
$hashTable.values.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object -Property DATE | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation  | Set-Content -path "$Reports\$($Store)_$(Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd)_$((Get-Date).tostring("hh-mm-ss")).csv" -force
```

I would like to add a line in script to add a filter (Filter By Selected Cell's Values) to one of the columns, is there a way this can be done.

Comment: You can't add a filter to a csv file. It would have to be an Excel file format.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the column before it gets written to the CSV file, then use the `Where-Object` command.

If you want to filter the column after it gets written to the CSV file, @BigBen is correct, you can't do that with a CSV file. You'll have to make it an Excel file and then you can use one of the various Excel Powershell modules or the native COM objects to apply a filter.

Comment: after converting .csv file to .xlsx, do you have an example of one of the Excel Powershell modules that can add a filter to one of the columns?

Comment: I use the [ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) module for working with Excel files in Powershell. However, I prefer to organize and manipulate the data in Powershell before I output to Excel or a CSV file so I'm not sure how to apply a filter in an Excel file. They have many example projects though that you can look through to find the feature you want.